# Ubuntu 17.10 Anyconnect vpnagentd.service: Start operation timed out

Tags: 17.10, vpn, cisco

Hi I have problem installing anyconnect-linux64-4.5.03040

```
  vpnagentd.service - LSB: Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client for Linux
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/vpnagentd; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Thu 2018-01-18 12:18:01 CET; 1min 41s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 3705 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/vpnagentd start (code=killed, signal=TERM)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 1.6M
      CPU: 11ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/vpnagentd.service
           ├─1549 plymouth --ping
           └─3708 plymouth --ping

led 18 12:13:01 marta systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client for Linux...
led 18 12:18:01 marta systemd[1]: vpnagentd.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
led 18 12:18:01 marta systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client for Linux.
led 18 12:18:01 marta systemd[1]: vpnagentd.service: Unit entered failed state.
led 18 12:18:01 marta systemd[1]: vpnagentd.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: so far I tried:

- Install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5
- Install network-manager-openconnect network-manager-openconnect-gnome
- Install different versions (4.2.01022) but I have problem with this error: vpnagentd.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units. After running systemctl daemon-reload error occurs again. Reboot or reinstall vpn client did not helped.
- and ofc. many reinstalls of vpn client and reboots

To be honest I have no idea, what can I do with timeouting vpnagentd.service.

EDIT2: 
I already gived up to set up vpn. But thanks to comment I walked through my tries and I installed anyconnect-4.3.05017 (after first run client was updated to 4.4.03034). Surprise! This version works! Many thanks guys.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the network manager integration for this:

```
sudo apt install network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openconnect network-manager-openvpn-gnome network-manager-openconnect-gnome
```

and then configuring the openconnect library to connect to your VPN rather than the Cisco client.